# Marking duplicates in a chain?

Tags: support, duplicates, closing-questions

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this question.

1. I originally created this question: [Is Power Word Kill's save DC from the Orcus' lair a typo?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131886/31402), which stems from a typo found in MToF.
2. It was indicated that it was a duplicate of this question: [What ability is the save DC of Orcus's “voice” Lair action, in Out of the Abyss?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89222/31402), which is the same issue but from a different book; so I didn't think it fulfilled the criteria of a duplicate.
3. The duplicate vote was retracted and the question re-opened, but another duplicate was identified and I concur it is a dupe of that one since it refers to MToF: [How should a save DC given for a spell that doesn't have one be interpreted?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/123380/31402), but this is marked as a duplicate of question 2 (not sure I would agree).

Unfortunately, I cannot link to the third question as a duplicate because it does not have any answers. Is it possible to bypass this, I'm reticent to link to question 2 as the means to that point stems from a different book and although the issue is the same, I'd like to demonstrate that the issue is more widespread.

I want to mark question 1 as a duplicate of question 3. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just point it to question 2 if you feel it's a valid duplicate, or leave it open if it's not a duplicate of that question.

Like you said, it doesn't have any answers. We cannot make duplicates pointing to questions that do not have answers.

We should not *try* to make chain duplicates. They're a sign of organisation failure: “your answer is over here” should lead immediately to the answer, not to “actually it's over there instead”. That we cannot close #1 as a dupe of #3 is a safety guard, not a problem to work around. For that reason although there might be some super fiddly workarounds, we shouldn't be going out of our way to use them anyway.

Comment: As a moderator, *you* could close it as a duplicate even without the other question having any answers. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/323179) for more info.

Comment: @Laurel Oh hey, TIL. Thanks for that.